# How to blend two dependent repositories data to create a single UI model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, repository

I am working on a MVC project with Repository pattern and ran into a situation very common in applications.

I have a View that displays Customer information and uses Customer and Account repository.
Account provide data like addresses,emails,phone, order history etc. while customer fills in personal info and customer choices. (sometimes overlapping info between two). However I cannot get Account data before customer.

Now in View I have only one UI entity [uxCustomer] that closely represents a View (MVC). Now we first have to call CustomerRepository to

```
   => Fill Customer info (partially)
   => Get AccountID to call AccountRepository
```

**I have thought of following options:**

1. Call AccountRepository from within the CustomerRepository to return a complete [uxCustomer] instead of partial.
2. From controller call CustomerReposioty to get partial [uxCustomer] and then call AccountRepository and pass the partial [uxCustomer] ByRef so that it can be populated with info not available in CustomerRepository.
3. Create two new Entity [BusinessCustomer] and [BusinessAccount] (to be returned by respective Repository) and have a middle layer between Repository and Controller, lets call it Processor. And let Processor perform the step2 and return [uxCustomer]

Please provide your inputs.

PS: I do not control Service/DataAccessLayer so have to work with what I have.

Comment: Is there no way for you to eager load the Accountinfo from the CustomerRepository, considering there will be a link between the two entities?

Comment: @pEko, Do you mean Option2 having an object of AccountRepository accessible to CustomerRepository? To me it defeats the purpose of having Respository pattern when repositories have cross reference. May be I did not grasp your idea completely.

Comment: No, I don't mean first get part of the data and then use that to get the other part. In your entities you presumably have a link from on entity (Customer) to the other Entity (Account), by way of a foreign key? Say for instance your Account has a property `public int CustomerID`, and your `Customer` entity then has a `public virtual Account Account`, with this setup you could also tell the repository to eager load the virtual properties of the `Customer` entity. If there's not link then I would certainly advise you to look at that.